# Import/Export Meteor Collections

Tags: mongodb, import, export, meteor

I'd like to be able to provide an import/export to `csv` feature for a specific Subscription (a subset of a Collection). However, I'm not sure at all where I should start. I assume that this has to be done server-side since they need to upload a file for the importing feature, so it probably involves a `Meteor.methods` function on the server which I call from the client. I'm not sure how you would return a file for download or temporarily upload one (for the import feature, I don't want to keep the file around).

Any ideas on the best way to approach this with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pretend this is the best way, but do check out [CollectionFS](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS), a Meteor package that implements file uploads, so a logged-in user can upload files, and file handlers, in this sense, a function or series of functions automatically run on an uploaded file.

For exports, you could pipe this through CollectionFS again, or you could use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to just directly serve the export file.